# How to write a method that stores words backward in an arraylist received from user input until "done" is entered?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Write a method that continuously reads words from a user until the word entered is “done” and stores each word spelled backwards in an ArrayList in the order they were entered.

This is the code I have so far but whenever I try to call it in my main class it keeps failing. Can someone please help me? I have included both the class in which I am creating my method and the main class in which it is called. I cannot combine these two classes so I need to be able to call the object from todo in my main class. Thanks in advance!

Sample input: banana racecar puppy done
Resulting ArrayList: ananab racecar yppup

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList; 

public class todo extends main{


    public ArrayList <String>storeBackwards (Scanner keyboard) {
        ArrayList<String> words=new ArrayList (); 
        ArrayList<String> backwards=new ArrayList(); 

        String input=keyboard.next();
        while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
            words.add(input); 
            String get=""; 
            String back=""; 
            for(int i=0; i<words.size();++i) {
                get=words.get(i);
                for(i=get.length()-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    back=back+get.charAt(i); }
                backwards.add(back);
                }

            }
        return backwards;


        }
    }
```

This is the main class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in); 
    todo x=new todo(); 

    x.storeBackwards(keyboard);


}

}
```

Comment: why your todo class extends from main ?

Comment: Provide the Sample Input and Expected output

Comment: Sample input: banana racecar puppy done
Resulting ArrayList: ananab racecar yppup

Answer (score 1):

Here in your code `String input=keyboard.next();` you are calling the `keyboard.next()` only once. So the value of the String variable `input` is unchanged after the first token is read.

So it results in the Infinite Loop and thats the reason you are getting the Exception

And the loop variable used in both of the for loops is `int i`, Use the different variable like `int j` for the **nested for loop**

`for(int j=get.length()-1; j>=0; j--) {
      back=back+get.charAt(j); 
 }`

**After modification of Your code as below, your test case got cleared**

```
    public List<String> storeBackwards (Scanner keyboard) {
            ArrayList<String> backwards=new ArrayList<String>();        
            String input=keyboard.next();       
            while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
                String back="";             
                for(int j=input.length()-1; j>=0; j--) {
                    back=back+input.charAt(j); 
                }
                backwards.add(back);
                back="";            
                input=keyboard.next();           
            }
            return backwards;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use StringBuffer's predefined reverse() function as shown below code snippet:

```
ArrayList<String> backwards = new ArrayList();
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = keyboard.next();
     StringBuffer a = new StringBuffer(input);
    while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
        a = new StringBuffer(input);
        backwards.add(a.reverse().toString());
        input = keyboard.next();
    }
```